# Windows Service code gives threading error when using Pywin32 / PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, service, pywin32, pyinstaller

I'm getting an error when using a python exe generated from pyinstaller, to create a windows service.  The error message may be innocuous, and doesn't seem to effect the operation of the service, but I'm not sure if there are other problems going on behind the scenes.  I'm using the pywin32 libraries to install the application as a windows service.  I should note that I don't get this error when installing from the python script itself, using PythonService.exe from pywin32, only from the executable generated with pyinstaller.

When using pyinstaller, I can generate the exe from my windows service code and install it, no problem.  I can also start the service, no problem.  I can even stop the service and the application appears to shut down properly.  However, once I've initiated the stop, I get the following error on the console while running the win32traceutil.py:

```
"Exception KeyError: KeyError(2244,) in <module 'threading' from '2\build\pyi.win32\agentservice\outPYZ1.pyz/threading'> ignored"
```

No errors are recorded to the event log.  I've been able to trace it back to the python logging module.  Simply importing the logging module seems to cause my problem.  Commenting out the import eliminates the error.  It seems pretty clear to me that this is causing the problem, but I find it strange that pyinstaller would have issues with a module in the standard library.  Has anyone else run into this?

I'm running Python 2.6.6, Pyinstaller 1.5.1, Build 217 of Pywin32.  I'm on Windows XP.

And a stripped down version of my code:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
import win32traceutil
import servicemanager
import sys
import os
import time

class myservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "5"
    _svc_display_name_ = "5"
    _svc_deps_ = ["EventLog"]

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.isAlive = True
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def event_log(self, msg):
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(str(msg))

    def SvcStop(self):
        # tell Service Manager we are trying to stop (required)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)

        print "svcstop: stopping service, setting event"
        # set the event to call
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

        print "svcstop: ending svcstop"

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        print "we are starting the service..."
        self.event_log("Starting %s" % self._svc_name_)


    ############ IF LOGGING IS COMMENTED OUT, THE ERROR GOES AWAY################
        import logging
        print "svcdorun: waiting for object"
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop,win32event.INFINITE)
        print "svcdorun: return from function"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)==1:
        import win32traceutil
        print "service is starting..."

        #servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.Initialize('backup service', None)
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(myservice)
        # Now ask the service manager to fire things up for us...
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()

        print "service done!"
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(myservice)
```